# what´s the meaning of (<any>window).__karma__

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner

Hi guys I´m learning angular2, and I don´t know what´s the meaning of this line of code:

```
let loadingGif: string = ((<any>window).__karma__) ? '' : require('images/loadin\ g.gif');
```

Please, Can anyone help me with this?

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just checking if the environment is a karma test environment. If it is, then there is no need for a loading gif. If it's not the test enviroment, then it's the application environment, in which case, you should use the loading gif. The following is how you can easily check if the environment is a karma environment

```
((<any>window).__karma__)
```

karma add the `__karma__` property to the `window`

The `<condition> ? <truthy result> : <falsy result>` syntax is just a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). So basically the code reads, "if in karma environment, set loading gif to empty string, otherwise load the gif"

Answer (score 0):

It is a short version of:

```
var loadingGif = null;

if ((<any>window).__karma__ === undefined) {
    loadingGif  = '';
} else {
    loadingGif = require('images/loadin\ g.gif');
}
```

By default in browsers the global variable `window` don't have a property named `__karma__`. So the type of `window` is cast to `any` using the TypeScript casting syntax `<any>`.

The function `require` loads the `'images/loadin\ g.gif'` file.

And the variable `__karma__` comes from [the Karma test runner](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html).